# Swap every two nodes in linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, swap

Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its head. You must solve the problem without modifying the values in the list's nodes (i.e., only nodes themselves may be changed.)

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
 class ListNode(object):
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        cur =head
        while cur and cur.next:
            nxtPair=cur.next.next 
            second=cur.next
            cur.next=nxtPair
            second.next=cur
            cur=second 
            cur=cur.next.next       
        return head
```

```
   input:[1,2,3,4]
   output:
   [1,3]
   expected:
   [2,1,4,3]
```

I found a solution using dummy linkedlist but without using dummy linkedlist I didn't understand what mistake I made.
To have more clarity on this concept can anyone
help me with this problem.Here head is not being updated for example , If I have to swap 1,2 to 2,1..head is not being updated to 2,1 instead having only node with 1 as value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue here is that the swapping requires changing the `head` value.  Using a dummy list head is a perfectly valid way to do this.  That's how I solved it.  Then I return `dummyhead.next`.

Comment: The lines `cur=second; cur=cur.next.next` are incorrect. I think they should be replaced with just `cur = nxtPair`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am changing cur value right then it should get updated in head also ryt .

Comment: @Dennis Even after replacing them with cur=nxtPair , The ouput is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something different about the first pair swap as opposed to all pair swaps afterward: the first pair swap does not have a predecessor, but so you only need to update two linkages (and remember to change the head), while future updates require you to go back to the predecessor and update it, and so you need three linkage updates.

So there is some special handling of the first case. You could either give the list a dummy head so that the first swap updates its predecessor just like the rest of the swaps, or you can peel off the first loop like this:

```py
def swapPairs(head):
    if head and head.next:
        # Before: (head=c1) --> c2 --> c3
        #  After: (head=c2) --> c1 --> c3
        c1 = head
        c2 = c1.next
        c3 = c2.next
        head = c2
        c2.next = c1
        c1.next = c3
        cur = c1

        while cur.next and cur.next.next:
            # Before: cur --> c1 --> c2 --> c3
            #  After: cur --> c2 --> c1 --> c3
            c1 = cur.next
            c2 = c1.next
            c3 = c2.next
            cur.next = c2
            c2.next = c1
            c1.next = c3
            cur = c1

    return head
```

(or you could keep a "prev" variable and add an "if this isn't the first loop..." condition, like in Andrew Parmar's solution)

Comment: the above code is not giving correct output. output:[2,3,4,1]

Comment: Thanks, I think it should work now. All the same ideas.

Comment: @AnushaYerram I edited the code to fix the bug and make it more obvious exactly where the first loop differs from the rest (`head = c2` versus `cur.next=c2`).

Comment: I would like to cover an edge case if head=[] then return head directly.Thank you so much.I understood what you did but still I am unable to visualize it.

Comment: if `head` is `None` (which I'm assuming is how you represent the empty list), then this should immediately return `None`, so I think that should be okay. I added some comments.

Comment: @Dennis, you can avoid treating the first loop as different and make the function recursive, if you just always return the head of every pair. Also, you can use the make use of the swap pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are updating `head`. After you do your first swap, you need to reassign head. Most likely, your dummy node is properly pointing to the correct "new" head and so it works.

Here is a working implementation without a dummy node.

```
class Solution:
    def swapPairs(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        new_head = None
        curr = head
        prev = None
        
        if curr and not curr.next:
            return curr
        
        while curr and curr.next:
            next_ = curr.next
            next_next = next_.next
            print(curr.val, next_.val, prev.val if prev else None)
            
            curr.next = next_next
            next_.next = curr
            if prev:
                prev.next = next_

            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next
            
            if not new_head:
                print("setting head", next_.val)
                new_head = next_

        return new_head
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You gotta love python, it makes it possible to implement such operation as simply as this:

```
def swap_pairs(n):
  if n and n.next:
    head = n.next
    head.next, n.next = n, swap_pairs(head.next)
    return head
  return n
```

There is a lot going on here:

- no `head` second argument is needed in the function (provided that is mutates the original list). Also, you can return the head in every recurrence call, and only the first one will be seen back in the original call site.
- the swap idiom with tuple assignment (`a, b = b, a`) is one of the most elegant and underrated python features. Note that the order is important: if you had `n.next, head.next` instead, you could end up with an infinite recursion or something worse.

Here is a simple unit test for it:

```
class ListNode:
  def __init__(self, val, next=None):
    self.val, self.next = val, next
  def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.val} {self.next or '.'}"
  @classmethod
  def of(cls, val, *rest):
    return cls(val, cls.of(*rest) if rest else None)

print(swap_pairs(ListNode.of(1, 2, 3, 4)))  # 2 1 4 3 .
print(swap_pairs(ListNode.of(1, 2, 3)))     # 2 1 3 .
print(swap_pairs(ListNode.of(1, 2)))        # 2 1 .
print(swap_pairs(ListNode.of(1)))           # 1 .
```